# M2: Use extra css file in addition to LESS compiled styles

Tags: magento2, theme, css, modman

Is there a way to add an additional CSS-File to theme?

In `default_head_blocks.xml` I added my css file via

```
<css src="css/override.css" />
```

My shop therefore looks for

```
domain.tld/pub/static/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/[locale]/css/override.css
```

I added the file override.css in `[Vender]/[Theme]/web/css/override.css` and used `setup:static-content:deploy` to build my theme. 
But then, the override.css doesn't appear in `pub/static/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/[locale]/css/`

What did I missed to do?

Comment: Ok, after few trying I used "--verbose" to get more output: It seems that my file (symlink) doesn't seem to be a file: Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write->assertIsFile() throws an error. 

More soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was my pre-build of my magento2 box:

I used `modman` to `link` external template directory in magento2 `app\design\frontend\`

If I used `copy as modman deployment` strategy `setup:static-content:deploy`works fine.

So use `modman deploy-all --copy --force` as command .